# Definition of a Cauchy sequence in terms of a Cauchy filter

Tags: general-topology, cauchy-sequences, filters, uniform-spaces

**Prerequisites** in case you may need and I am correct about them:

An [**entourage**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Entourage_definition) is a member of uniformity structure on a set for it to be a uniform space. Intuitively, an entourage is a relation on a set, such that it specifies those pairs of points,  the "between-distance" for each pair being bounded by some "value" specified by the entourage. It is easier to understand for a metric space, which is an example of uniform space.

---

1. The definition I know for a Cauchy sequence in a uniform space is

   > A sequence $(x_i)$ is a **Cauchy sequence** if  for every entourage $V$
   > there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $i, j ≥ n$, $(x_i,  x_j)$ is a member of $V$.
2. From [Planetmath](https://planetmath.org/completeuniformspace), the definition for a Cauchy sequence in a
   uniform space is

   > A **Cauchy sequence** $x_i$ in a uniform space $X$ is a sequence in $X$
   > whose **section filter** is a Cauchy filter,

   where the **section filter** of a sequence is defined to be the
   maximal proper filter containing the filter base generated by the
   sequence, if I understand [its definition](https://planetmath.org/sectionfilter) correctly.
3. This definition of Cauchy sequence surprises  me, because I was
   thinking instead

   > A **Cauchy sequence** $x_i$ in a uniform space $X$ is a sequence in $X$
   > whose **filter** is a Cauchy filter,

   where the **filter** of a sequence is the minimal filter containing
   the filter base generated by the sequence.

So I wonder if the three definitions are equivalent?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I am not familiar with the notion of "entourage"; could you provide the definition?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: An entourage is a member of uniformity structure on a set for it to be a uniform space. Wiki has the description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Entourage_definition). It is easier to understand for a metric space, which is an example of uniform space. Intuitively, an entourage is a relation on a set, such that it specifies those pairs of points,  the "distance" for each is within some "value".

Comment: Please put relevant definitions in the body of the post; don't force people, like myself, who are unfamiliar with the term to wade into the comments to find out what the words mean.

Comment: @Arturo: For the record, I would expect anyone with a basic knowledge of uniform spaces to be familiar with the term *entourage*, just as I’d expect anyone with a basic knowledge of topological spaces to be familiar with the term *neighborhood*.

Comment: @Brian: Fair enough; I'm not familiar with either...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Still there is no doubt you are very knowledgeable and an expert in many areas. I wish I could match up 1/10 of your knowledge.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I would think entourage to uniformity is more similar to open subset to topology.

Comment: @Tim: I wasn’t trying for a close analogy; I was just trying to indicate that it wasn’t surprising that you omitted the definition.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I was just kidding. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: This post came to my attention because of the broken PlanetMath link, "its definition".  Their topic page [section filter](https://planetmath.org/sectionfilter) seems to be an apt replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalence of (1) and (3) is standard. The PlanetMath definition of *section filter* is simply wrong: it doesn’t define a unique object, since the filter generated by the sections (or tails, as I prefer to call them) may have many maximal extensions.